# how to add widget in submenu of wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, menu

I want to add widget in second layer of wordpress menu. and it should be changable from admin panel. as for example if i add calendar widget in second layer than it can be move to another menu or should be able to add another widget.

Comment: I'd recommend getting a plugin to support widgets in a menu like [UberMenu](http://wpmegamenu.com/). There is no "simple" way to do that.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Is there no other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little too late, but here's the solution I've found to this problem. It might still be helpful to someone out there ;P

First I tried making use of the Max Mega Menu plugin, it was giving too many features I didn't need besides the ability to add widgets to the menu.

But the following plugin takes care of that in a very simple and practical way: [Widgets in Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widgets-in-menu/).

Give it a try, this one did it for me ;)